# Time format when using pandas.to_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a out put from a Pandas `DataFrame` as following.

```
   id value                exit               enter  time_diff
0   1     a 2012-11-27 10:41:20 2012-11-27 10:39:00   00:02:20
1   2     a 2012-12-07 06:00:10 2012-12-07 06:00:09   00:00:01
2   2     c 2012-12-27 06:05:17 2012-12-27 06:00:17   00:05:00
3   3     a 2012-12-27 06:00:13 2012-12-27 06:00:13   00:00:00
```

Why following doesn’t work?

```
df.to_csv('diff.csv', date_format='%H:%M:%S')
```

For the first one in csv following is there for time_diff

```
140000000000
```

Comment: the date_format argument does not apply to timedelta dtypes. Easist to simply convert them to strings first, e.g. ``df[timedelta_field'] = df['timedelta_fields'].apply(str)``

Answer (score 1):

Time diff is an integer given in nanoseconds, not a date. I would recommend either pickling or hdf5 if you need to round-trip.